# How do one read the Zookeeper transaction log?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Are there any existing tools that help to read the Zookeeper transaction log? By default, it is in binary format and I would like to read it in human readable form.

Answer (score 38):

I don't know if you have solved this question.

```
cd /your/zookeeper/directory/
```

If you want to read snapshots, use:

```
java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar org.apache.zookeeper.server.SnapshotFormatter version-2/snapshot.xxx
```

If you want to read logs, use:

```
java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter version-2/log.xxx
```

Comment: 4 years later and your post is still helpful! 

Thanks a bunch Oliver and Tony.

I was attempting to run this command on the server log inside of the logs folder (not realizing I was meant to run it on the transaction logs...)

Comment: with zookeeper 3.5.6 this worked for me (updated jar names and had to add jute): `java -cp lib/zookeeper-3.5.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:lib/zookeeper-jute-3.5.6.jar`

Comment: The LogFormatter tool is removed in 3.7

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like this

`java -cp $ZOOKEEPER_CLASSPATH  org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter [zookeeper log file path]`

Comment: I can't make it work. Keeps returning `Error: Could not find or load main class log.5200768f38`

Comment: @Eye - You need a valid value for `ZOOKEEPER_CLASSPATH` set before you can execute Vikas's command. I personally prefer to simply reuse HBase's classpath setup: `hbase org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter <filename>` which automatically loads the class.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the previous two answers, using Zookeeper 3.5.6: from the `/path/to/zookeeper/lib` dir which contains all the ZK and supporting jars run:

`java -cp * org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter /path/to/zookeeper/transaction/logs/version-2/log.xxx`

Answer (score 1):

Since zookeeper version 3.6 there are tools to read transaction log and snapshots in zookeeper distribution:

For transaction log:

```
bin/zkTxnLogToolkit.sh --dump /datalog/version-2/log.f3aa6
```

For snapshots:

```
./zkSnapShotToolkit.sh -d /data/zkdata/version-2/snapshot.fa01000186d
```

See the details in [official docs](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/236e3d9183606512f0e03a1f828ad0d392eb6091/zookeeper-docs/src/main/resources/markdown/zookeeperTools.md#zkTxnLogToolkit)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ZooKeeper audit logs for ZooKeeper 3.6.o and upwards. To enable audit logs configure audit.enable=true in conf/zoo.cfg.

One thing to keep in mind is that logs from different servers of the same ensemble should be aggregated because each one of them includes operations that where executed only form clients connected to this particular server.

Full information here: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperAuditLogs.html